# SetTitle for buttons in iPhone SDK > 3.0

Tags: iphone, button

Today I have installed iPhone SDK 3.1 along with appropriate XCode. The thing that happened is that all of my buttons have lost their titles. Here is my code for button creation:

```
UIButton *dateButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240.0, 57.0, 60.0, 30.0)];
        [dateButton setTitle:@"Date" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [dateButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [dateButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_headline.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [dateButton addTarget:self action:@selector(GoToDateSettings:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:dateButton];
```

Any ideas what is the problem? This code worked flawlessly in < 2.2 SDKs

Regardz,
Mladen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy and Paste: Should be self explanatory. Behavior changed in SDK 3.x. Cheers, Jordan

```
        UIButton *dateButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [dateButton setFrame:CGRectMake(240.0, 57.0, 60.0, 30.0)];
        [dateButton setTitle:@"Date" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [dateButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [dateButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_headline.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [dateButton addTarget:self action:@selector(GoToDateSettings:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:dateButton];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[dateButton.titleLabel setTitle:@"Date" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

UILabels and UITableView cells are now more customizable in 3.0+.  I found this directly from looking in the docs for UIButton.

Comment: Can't call it on the titleLabel... [dateButton setTitle:forState]